# If I get a certificate signed for ECDSA will older browsers be able to use RSA?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, tls, rsa

I'm looking into using ECDHE-ECDSA and there are a lot of great articles on why (https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/) and (http://blog.cloudflare.com/ecdsa-the-digital-signature-algorithm-of-a-better-internet), for example.

Obviously the browser support isn't great, but Chrome 30, Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8, Safari 7 on OS X 10.9, and Firefox 26 all support TLS 1.2.

I have looked into a few CAs and only a few sign certificates for ECDSA (Verisign/Symantec  does). My question is: if I get a certificate signed for ECDSA and in my cipher chain I fall back properly, will older browsers be able to use RSA?

I have the feeling that the answer is no, because if you sign an RSA certificate, you can't use ECDSA, but I wanted to make sure before I ruled out ECDHE-ECDSA.

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this Q/A over on Information Security SE:

[Is possible that a TLS server send more than one certificate to the client for the same site?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43360/is-possible-that-a-tls-server-send-more-than-one-certificate-to-the-client-for-t)

Strictly speaking, the server *can* send an arbitrary number of certificates to the client, as part of its `Certificate` message. However, as [the standard says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2):

> The sender's
> certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.

Therefore, a really compliant server cannot send a choice of certificates to the client, and cannot expect clients to use any other certificate than the first one they send.

For **signature algorithm support**, there is a standard *TLS extension* specified in [section 7.4.1.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.4.1), by which the client can tell to the server, early in the handshake (in the `ClientHello`, which is the very first message of the procedure), which hash functions and signature algorithms it supports. This allows a server who owns, for instance, both a RSA-signed certificate and an ECDSA-signed certificate, to send one or the other, depending on what the client supports. This is typical of how things go in TLS: the client suggests, the server chooses.

(In practice, support for this extension is not yet widespread. But, also in practice, everybody uses RSA and supports RSA.)

Comment: See new comment on the security.SE question: if your server can configure both an RSA key&cert AND an ECDSA one (which depends on the server, Apache uses openssl and apparently can) then it can and must use the correct key&cert (sent as the first cert) for the ciphersuite negotiated.